# css background transparency across browser

Tags: css, cross-browser, transparency

I have assigned an rgba color with transparency value of 0.2 to my menu, it works fine on chrome and safari, but on firefox and IE the menu turns to white. Attached in the link to website http://www.lensshare.io/

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question **itself**, rather than simply linking to your website (which could harbor malicious content).

Comment: Read this: https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 1):

You can use instead of `rgba` use `rgb` and `opacity:0.2`

Answer (score 0):

try removing position: relative on the elements body header also nice site[image]